# Parental form give NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

When I try to change the label in the parent form it gives me a NullReferenceException.

Form1

```
    public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return label1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            label1.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form2

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Form1)ParentForm).LabelText = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe ParentForm is null?

Comment: You haven't told Form2 that it has a parent form. Do this: `Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You should check `Owner` form instead of `ParentForm`. And you should pass owner when opening second form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Form1)Owner).LabelText = textBox1.Text;
    this.Close();
}
```

But that's still not the best way to pass data between forms. Create public properties on `Form2` form and read their values in `Form1` *if* `DialogResult` returned `OK` after closing child form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(Form2 f2 = new Form2())
    {
        if (f2.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
           return;

        LabelText = f2.SomeValue;   
    }
}
```

[Whats the difference between Parentform and Owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377212/whats-the-difference-between-parentform-and-owner)